# Building a cart in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have built a client side cart in angularjs, my application allows me to sell tickets, all kinds of tickets; bus, airline, train etc.

Now i have a page for each type of ticket i want to sell.  Each page has it's own controller and scope.

Now my problem is since each page has it's on controller and scope and my cart also has it's own controller and scope whenever i add an item from the ticket page, i store it in a scope object, save it in the localStorage and broadcast a value(CartUpdated) of true or false.  Now in the cart controller it watches for that broadcast and gets the cart from localStorage and saves it in a new scope object, after which i loop through it and display the contents in the cart.

My issues here is i keep having to deal with multiple scope objects for a single operation.

I have to update the scope in my ticket controller and then update the scope in my cart controller.

What i want to know is is there a way i can make my cart global within my application? Sort of like a static class with static values easily accessed from any controller at all in my application.

This will mean that all functions: Add, Remove, Update, will be located in the cart controller itself and i will simply call them from all my ticket pages instead of the way i have it now with add on y ticket page and Remove and Update on my cart.

Comment: Sounds like the perfect place to use an angular service. That is how we handle our cart updates to keep everything in sync.The addToCart() function calls the service which gets the item and then updates the cart display.

Comment: But with that service, i need to create another instance of it in my cart controller, meaning i will still need to broadcast and watch for updates.

Comment: What i mean is with a service i can access the functions but what about the data? Is the data that is being passed from one controller to a service accessible by another controller assuming it uses the same service?

Comment: service with one cart object is all you need, create refernce to that anywhere within app

Comment: Is the object that is being passed from one controller to a service accessible by another controller assuming it uses the same service?

Comment: You need to read up on what object inheritance is. There is only one object...all pointers to it are merely references to the same object. The object is not being *passed around*

Comment: Oh yes i do know that, what i actually meant was the data in the object itself not the actual object.